# A Combinatorial Problem from HMMT-2009

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

I've been stuck on a problem from HMMT-2009. I understand the main part of the problem and the answer. My problem with the solution is the last part of it:
`Given a rearrangement of the numbers from 1 to n, each pair of consecutive elements a and b of the sequence can be either increasing or decreasing. How many rearrangements have of the numbers from 1 to n have exactly two increasing pairs?`

My answer:
Well, obviously we can split these numbers into three partitions and subtract off the undesirable rearrangements. To do so, the number of total counts is $3^n$

Now, we don't wanna count those rearrangements that have 1 or 0 increasing pairs. The partitions whose associated permutation has exactly one increasing pair can be counted by splitting the numbers into two subsets with 1 increasing pair first, which gives us $2^n-(n+1)$, and after that we split these rearrangements into another subset, and we'll have three subsets. There are $n+1$ ways to do that. So far we have
$3^n-(n+1)(2^n-(n+1))$ according to the multiplication principle.
Now, my problem begins when we start trying to find the number of rearrangements with no increasing pair. The solution says 
There are $\frac{n+2}{2}$ ways of placing two barriers between these elements to split the numbers into three subsets, and so there are $\frac{n+2}{2}$ such partitions of {1,2,..,n} into three subsets. Thus, the answer is
$$
3^n-(n+1)(2^n-(n+1))-{n+2 \choose 2}=3^n-(n+1)2^n+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$

How did we get that last part ${n+2 \choose 2}$

Comment: Could the write-up have a typo?  $\frac{n+2}{2}$ need not be an integer.  I think it should read ${n+2}\choose{2}$, which would be normal for choosing $2$ barriers in an $n$-set... there are $n+2$ symbols among $n$ numbers and $2$ barriers, and you choose $2$ to be the barriers.

Comment: Actually, I think it can't be right too. But that's what's written in the official solution. Here, look https://hmmt-archive.s3.amazonaws.com/tournaments/2009/feb/comb/solutions.pdf, the last problem

Comment: So, do you think the official solution can be wrong after about 13 years? I mean that's not impossible but is it that likely?

Comment: If you try for small values of $n$ it should become clear that it is a mistake.  I think I learned this in terms of toothpicks.  Take $n=100$, lay out $102$ toothpicks.  Choose two toothpicks to be the barriers, the other $100$ toothpicks are the numbers of $1,2,..,100$ in decreasing order.

Comment: Definitely. It is wrong for any odd value of n

Comment: but, just another question. Why n+2? How would ${n+2 \choose 2}$ make any sense?

Comment: sorry, see my edit above

Comment: oh. That makes sense. Thank you man/ms

Comment: Looking at the [solution](https://hmmt-archive.s3.amazonaws.com/tournaments/2009/feb/comb/solutions.pdf), the author used $\frac{n+2}{2}$ twice, and $\binom{n+2}{2}$ once at the end, so one of these is likely a typo. In LaTeX, these are typeset using the commands `\frac{n+2}{2}` and `\binom{n+2}{2}`; it is easy to get these mixed up (at least, I do it all the time).

Answer (score 1):

So, as it appears the stated solution is wrong whereas the mathematical solution is right. I understood it thanks to [user136920](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/136920/user136920)

The part that says $\frac{n+2}{2}$ is the number of ways we can rearrange it using two barriers was actually meant to be ${n+2 \choose 2}$ that should somehow make sense but still unfortunately I can't understand why. One user said we can imagine the elements and the barrier as toothpicks but if we do that how could $n+2 \choose 2$ do the trick and how would that get rearranged, becuase using that we are basically choosing them, not rearranging them?